# How to create a macro for a string variable

Tags: macros, system-verilog

How can I use a variable for a macro definition in system verilog:
Example:

```
string string_var = "Hello"
define STRING_VAR_MACRO string_var
```

I want to make `STRING_VAR_MACRO` be `Hello` instead of `string_var`. Is there another way to achieve this? I don't want to do `define STRING_VAR_MACRO Hello` either for the purpose of my project

or the other option is I want `string_var` variable to be accessible globally through all files/modules

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0):

The way to make any variable *globally* accessible is putting in a package and referencing it explicitly or importing the package

```
package gbls;
  string string_var = "Hello"
endpackage
module my_module;
  initial $display(gbls::string_var);
endmodule
```